# How to implement Two Level Menu using Android Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android, android-fragments

How we can implement Two Level Menu using Android Navigation Drawer. It should work like this
1. When User will open Navigation Drawer, Patent Menu will be visible. (Screen Shot 1)
2. Once User click on specific item. Sub-Menu associated with that item will be open with Sliding in effect [Parent Menu will slide left and Sub Menu will appear from right sliding in] with an option to go back. (Screen Shot 2) 
[image][image]
I tried different solution like using ListItem visibility etc.

Comment: create your desire layout and add it to your `NavigationDrawar` rather then using `listView'

Comment: Use Expandable list view instead of menu, Remove navigationView from your layout.. and instead of that use Expandable listview.

Comment: @HimanshuShekherJha But in that case it will provide expandable/collapsable Sub menu option. My requirement is to have completely new menu (with submenu options) with slide in effect. I don't think that you can achieved through expandable list view.

Comment: Well we achieve sliding effect through expandable list view.

Comment: <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/selectOutlet"
        android:background="@color/navigation_drawer_background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

    </LinearLayout>

We use this in place of navigationview, and inflate exapandable list view dynamically.

Comment: @HimanshuShekherJha Please elaborate how can we use Sliding Effect though Expandable List View

Comment: Well You only need to Replace Navigation view with your particular view in XML and Java file. Code inside NavigationView and Your replaced view will we same in xml.

Comment: how how sliding effect will take place ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107321/discussion-between-alex-and-himanshu-shekher-jha).

Comment: @Alex Please share your solution, and mark your own answer as the accepted solution :)